# Error in installing caffe in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: opencv, cmake, caffe

Having already required dependencies for caffe installation:
in cmake step, when I use:

```
cmake ..
```

I get this error:

```
-- Python:
--   Interpreter       :   /home/majid/anaconda/bin/python2.7 (ver..2.7.9)
--   Libraries         :   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.6)
--   NumPy             :   /home/majid/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.9.2)
```

which in Libraries it has detected wrong path instead of /home/majid/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.so

I tried to force to use the correct path by:

```
cmake -D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/home/majid/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.so ..
```

but after:

```
make all -j $(nproc)
```

I am getting a couple of time this warning:

```
At end of source: warning: routine is both "inline" and "noinline"
```

in the end it stops by this error:

```
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.8: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBAStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 make[2]: *** [examples/cpp_classification/classification] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/classification.dir/all] Error 2
 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

while when installing opencv I used this cmake:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/majid/opencv -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/majid/anaconda/bin/python2.7 -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/majid/anaconda/include/python2.7 -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS=/home/majid/anaconda/include/python2.7 -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR2=/home/majid/anaconda/include/python2.7 -D PYTHON_LIBRARIES=/home/majid/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.so -D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/home/majid/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.so -D PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/home/majid/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D PYTHON2_LIBRARY=/home/majid/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.so -D PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/home/majid/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy -D BUILD_opencv_python3=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_python2=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D BUILD-TIFF=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON -D MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS=/home/majid/MATLAB/extern/include -D MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS=/home/majid/MATLAB/bin -D MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT=/home/majid/MATLAB/bin -D MATLAB_ROOT_DIR=/home/majid/MATLAB ..
```

in which it is: LIBTIFF=ON.

after making opencv I set the packages' path by:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/majid/opencv/lib
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/home/majid/opencv/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

and also:

```
sudo /bin/bash -c 'echo "/home/majid/opencv/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf'
sudo ldconfig
```

I don't know why I am having this problem from x86-64-linux-gnu while I have the same libopencv-highgui.so in the /home/majid/opencv/lib

I really appreciate it if someone could help me out in this matter.

the result of forced cmake:

```
cmake -D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/home/majid/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.so ..
-- Boost version: 1.55.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
-- Found gflags  (include: /usr/local/include, library: /usr/local/lib/libgflags.a)
-- Found glog    (include: /usr/local/include, library: /usr/local/lib/libglog.so)
-- Found PROTOBUF Compiler: /usr/local/bin/protoc
-- Found lmdb    (include: /usr/local/include, library: /usr/local/lib/liblmdb.so)
-- Found LevelDB (include: /usr/local/include, library: /usr/local/lib/libleveldb.so)
-- Found Snappy  (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/libsnappy.so)
-- CUDA detected: 7.0
-- Found cuDNN (include: /usr/local/cuda-7.0/include, library: /usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64/libcudnn.so)
-- Added CUDA NVCC flags for: sm_21
-- Cuda + Boost 1.55: Applying noinline work around
-- OpenCV found (/usr/share/OpenCV)
-- Found Atlas (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/libatlas.so)
-- Found PythonLibs: /home/majid/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.so (found suitable version "2.7.6", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- NumPy ver. 1.9.2 found (include: /home/majid/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include)
-- Boost version: 1.55.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
-- Detected Doxygen OUTPUT_DIRECTORY: ./doxygen/
-- 
-- ******************* Caffe Configuration Summary *******************
-- General:
--   Version           :   <TODO> (Caffe doesn't declare its version in headers)
--   Git               :   rc2-344-g7e5608f-dirty
--   System            :   Linux
--   C++ compiler      :   /usr/bin/c++
--   Release CXX flags :   -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -Wall -Wno-sign-compared-Wno-uninitialized
--   Debug CXX flags   :   -g -fPIC -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Build type        :   Release
-- 
--   BUILD_SHARED_LIBS :   ON
--   BUILD_python      :   ON
--   BUILD_matlab      :   OFF
--   BUILD_docs        :   ON
--   CPU_ONLY          :   OFF
-- 
-- Dependencies:
--   BLAS              :   Yes (Atlas)
--   Boost             :   Yes (ver. 1.55)
--   glog              :   Yes
--   gflags            :   Yes
--   protobuf          :   Yes (ver. 3.0.0)
--   lmdb              :   Yes (ver. 0.9.14)
--   Snappy            :   Yes (ver. 1.1.0)
--   LevelDB           :   Yes (ver. 1.17)
--   OpenCV            :   Yes (ver. 2.4.8)
--   CUDA              :   Yes (ver. 7.0)
-- 
-- NVIDIA CUDA:
--   Target GPU(s)     :   Auto
--   GPU arch(s)       :   sm_21
--   cuDNN             :   Yes
-- 
-- Python:
--   Interpreter       :   /home/majid/anaconda/bin/python2.7 (ver. 2.7.9)
--   Libraries         :   /home/majid/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.6)
--   NumPy             :   /home/majid/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.9.2)
-- 
-- Documentaion:
--   Doxygen           :   /usr/bin/doxygen (1.8.6)
--   config_file       :   /home/majid/caffe/.Doxyfile
-- 
-- Install:
--   Install path      :   /home/majid/caffe/build/install
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/majid/caffe/build
```

Comment: Have you cleared your cache file or deleted your build directory? Maybe the old value is still cached.

Comment: @usr1234567 Yeah I've already done that. still there is conflict btw libraries in x86-64-linux-gnu and libraries in anaconda.